# Convex Hull of Rational Polyhedra, intersected with whole numbers

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-programming, polyhedra, convex-hulls

I am currently reading into polytope theory, and stumbled upon the following proposition, which I do not really understand:

> Let $$ P = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{k+l} \mid Ax\leq b\} $$ be a rational polyhedron, i.e., $A$ and $b$ are rational. Then $$\mbox{conv} (P \cap (\mathbb{Z}^k \times \mathbb{R}^l))$$ is also a rational polyhedron.

I do not understand what implications it has that the first k entries of the vectors are whole numbers. If they weren't, I'd think that the convex hull is a polyhedron nevertheless. So what does the first k entries being whole really mean? What does it change in the proof?

Comment: Note that the claim becomes false if the original matrix is not rational. E.g., the convex hull of $P\cap \Bbb Z^2$ where $P=\{(x,y)\mid y\le x\sqrt 2, x\ge 0\}$ has infinitely many edges

Comment: @Hagen Could You explain why A needs to be rational or otherwise we get infinetly many edges?